# Why is OUT0 incorrect?

Tags: microprocessor, assembly, proteus, 8085

The input frequency is 2 MHz and the output should be 2 kHz since I used mode 3 and the initial count value N=1000d.

The output frequency is 500kHz.

[image]

Comment: You sure you are doing what you think you are doing? Discerning PNs from your screenshot is impossible - for me - but I see that you are not using half of your address (or data?) bus...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the BCD mode and loading in a divider that is illegal BCD number.

Comment: When i use binary counter proutues freezes and shuts down

Comment: That's unfortunate but does it prevent you from using a valid BCD number?

Comment: can you suggest a value ?

Comment: Just convert any value 0-9999 to BCD, so 1000 in BCD should be fine.

Comment: you mean i have to write mov ax,0001 0000 0000 0000 b ?

Comment: If your assembler allows that notation, yes, that would be 1000 in BCD.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help ,But it didnt work too